# Creating own account system in appengine by unique emails

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to create my own account system and I know there is no unique fiels on datastore. I did some search about unique constraints and I found 2 way

first : emailaddress as keys,  so we can fast check is it exist, but this is not real world example.

second: using transactions,but datastore writes slow so I dont want to lock all records

What big apps using about custom accounting, is datastore proper for accounting?
Is there any documentation on developer.google.com about secure custom accounting?

thanks for anwswers...

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own Unique constraint on GAE (which is what the webapp2 auth module does):

- http://squeeville.com/2009/01/30/add-a-unique-constraint-to-google-app-engine/
- http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.html#webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.Unique

I would recommend not using the email address as the id of an entity because you can not change the id of an entity after it is created. If you ever need to let users change their email address you will have to create a new user entity for them and then update all references to that entity (reference properties in other entities) and re-create any child entities (entities for which the User entity is a parent).

One of the problems with checking uniqueness with a query on a property is that you cannot do a non-ancestor query within a transaction so, as far as I know, you cannot query for the uniqueness of a property value AND save a new entity with that unique value in the same transaction. This means there is a chance your query will say a property value is unique but by the time your entity is being written that value is no longer unique. The unique constraint code I linked above does not have this limitation because you are able to test to see if an id is unique within the same transaction that writes the new entity.

Note: What I refer to as an "id" above is called a key_name in the db library and an id in the ndb library.

Comment: Deleted my answer, yours is better :)